# Fantasy novel identification - greasy smoke precedes death

Tags: story-identification, sword-and-sorcery

I'd like to identify a fantasy novel I read, probably somewhere from the mid eighties to early nineties.

One problem is that I have read a lot of fantasy novels and it is highly likely that I will conflate parts of several novels if I say too much.  So, here is the one thing I remember that I want to know the story for:

A character on a quest of some sort got ill.  He had a cough that was accompanied by greasy smoke coming from his mouth.  He eventually died because of this.

Here are some other things that I believe came from the same story, but I cannot be sure.

- Swords and sorcery story.
- The ill man and his party were travelling by boat at the time.
- The character was a villager (possibly a farmer or blacksmith).
- He was a major character, or at least a long standing character.
- As the illness progressed he may have had mushrooms appear on his
  tongue.

Thanks in advance for any help working this one out!

Rotty

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's from Hugh Cook's *The Wizards and the Warriors*, first book of the *Chronicles of An Age of Darkness*.  The man in question was Blackwood, a hunter.  He contracted the smoke-sickness while travelling on a raft along a river in a tunnel, a journey which seems to have taken several days, if not weeks.  Ultimately, he had the sickness cured by drinking a draft composed of human blood and dragon blood.